# How to initialise the module TextRange after Aloha-Editor initialised Rangy?

Tags: rangy, aloha-editor

I'm using Aloha Editor for our WYSIWYG form. Since Aloha is using an old version of Rangy, and is initialised by Aloha, is there anyway I can initialise the module TextRange and CssClassApplier after?

Also, updating Rangy-Core dependency of Aloha is not an option right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The TextRange module uses API calls that are new in 1.3 so can't be plugged straight into 1.2.